# Remove all concurrences of a specific character from a string with string.Remove()

Tags: c#

```
public static string TextDecipher(string d)
{
    string textChars    = "@#^*+";
    string decipherText = "";
    string removeSymbol = "";

    char[] specialChars = textChars.ToCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < specialChars.Length; i++)
    {
        if (d.Contains(specialChars[0]))
        {
            removeSymbol = d.Remove(d.IndexOf('@'), 1);
            decipherText = removeSymbol.Insert(d.IndexOf(specialChars[0]), "a");
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(decipherText);
    return decipherText;
}
```

I've been trying to remove all concurrences of the character '@' from a string entered by a user. It removes the '@' if doesn't occurs 1 time, if it's more than 1, it only removes it one time.

Any suggestions as of I can go by solving the issue I'm having?

Comment: Use the Replace function.

Comment: I am not wanting to use replace. I want to use remove instead.

Comment: Then you'll need to write another loop that keeps removing that character for as long as it is found.

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you can't use the most appropriate method and must use the "Remove"?

Comment: A string can't have "concurrences" of characters. You seem to mean "occurrences".

Answer (score 1):

You have to run a continuous loop as long as a special character is found in your string.  The `while loop`, below, will continue to run as long as one of your special characters is found in the string.  If a special character is found, then it's removed from the string.  Otherwise, no special character was found and your loop ends.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string d = "The @quick @brown fox @jumps over @the lazy @dog";
        string textChars = "@#^*+";

        char[] specialChars = textChars.ToCharArray();

        Console.WriteLine("Before: {0}: ", d);
        bool specialCharFound = true;
        while (specialCharFound)
        {
            specialCharFound = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < specialChars.Length; i++)
            {   
                if (d.Contains(specialChars[i].ToString()))
                {
                    specialCharFound = true;
                    d = d.Remove(d.IndexOf(specialChars[i]), 1);                    
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("After : {0}: ", d);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Before: The @quick @brown fox @jumps over @the lazy @dog: 
After : The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog:
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/obPqvm)

### Enhancement

```
"I am not wanting to use replace."
```

Are you just referring to `String.Replace()`?  Because if you are, there's also `Regex.Replace()` that can take care of removing everything you want to remove without using loops.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string d = "The @quick @brown^#&*( fox @jumps over @the lazy @dog";
        Console.WriteLine("Before: {0}", d);
        d = Regex.Replace(d, "[^\\d\\w\\s]", string.Empty);
        Console.WriteLine("After : {0}", d);
    }
}
```

The regex pattern `"[^\\d\\w\\s]"` basically means replacing anything that is not (`^`) a number (`\\d`), letter (`\\w`), or white space (`\\s`) with an empty string (remove it).

Result:

```
Before: The @quick @brown^#&*( fox @jumps over @the lazy @dog
After : The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fiCK8Z)

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use **linq**, is `String.Remove()` compulsory? Here is what you want in just a few lines.

```
        string s = "Hello**@**Qg@e";
        Console.WriteLine("Original string : "+s);

        string s1 = string.Empty;
        var z = s.ToList();
        z.RemoveAll(x => x.Equals('@'));
        z.ForEach(x => s1 = s1 + x);
        Console.WriteLine("String after removal of '@' : " +s1);

        s1 = string.Empty;
        z.RemoveAll(x => x.Equals('*'));
        z.ForEach(x => s1 = s1 + x);
        Console.WriteLine("String after removal of '*' : " + s1);
```

[image: Demo]

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the method of removing inside a loop cause it removes just one character per time, like that:

```
    public static string TextDecipher(string text)
    {
        string textChars = "@#^*+";
        string decipherText = text;

        char[] specialChars = textChars.ToCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < specialChars.Length; i++)
        {
            var charOcurrences = text.ToCharArray().Count(c => c == specialChars[i]);

            if (charOcurrences > 0)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < charOcurrences; j++)
                {
                    var index = decipherText.IndexOf(specialChars[i]);
                    decipherText = decipherText.Remove(index, 1);
                }
            }
        }

        return decipherText;
    }
```

But remember if you use replace, the code would be more clear, like that:

```
    public static string TextDecipherWithReplace(string text)
    {
        var specialChars = "@#^*+".ToCharArray();
        var decipherText = text;

        foreach (var specialChar in specialChars)
        {
            decipherText = decipherText.Replace(specialChar.ToString(), "");
        }

        return decipherText;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are three choices for you to try:

```
public static string TextDecipher1(string d) =>
    Regex.Replace(d, $"[{Regex.Escape("@#^*+")}]", "");

public static string TextDecipher2(string d) =>
    "@#^*+".Aggregate(d, (a, x) => a.Replace(x.ToString(), ""));

public static string TextDecipher3(string d) =>
    String.Join("", "@#^*+".Aggregate(d.ToList(), (a, x) => {a.RemoveAll(c => c == x); return a; }));

Console.WriteLine(TextDecipher1("#$#@@ss"));
Console.WriteLine(TextDecipher2("#$#@@ss"));
Console.WriteLine(TextDecipher3("#$#@@ss"));
```

All produce `$ss` from the above example input.